# Why my redirect is not working...?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I am trying to make a redirect from my not `www` domain to my `www` domain like this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("http://mydomain.com"))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://www.mydomain.com");
            }
        }
```

For some reason the redirect is not done...(ok, I know this can be done by defining a `CNAME` also but I am simply wondering why this is not working...

I think it's something small buggy here...but I am not able to see it.

Comment: What's not working?  What does it look like in fiddler?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in debug mode to see whether the system enters the `if` statement?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I did not make debugging because I can only test it when I upload on the hosting side where this domain is...

Comment: I guess it's now even entering inside the if condition. You have to try some logging or response.write.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [tool](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) to verify. May be you have to change code little as below,

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("http://mydomain.com"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location",
               Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace(
                 "http://mydomain.com",
                 "http://www.mydomain.com"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark...Still not working...when testing with that tool, content is like: `<html><head><title>Object·moved</title></head><body>(CR)(LF)
<h2>Object·moved·to·<a·href="/ServerError?aspxerrorpath=/">here</a>.</h2>(CR)(LF)
</body></html>(CR)(LF)`